# What is the best way to save composer dependencies across multiple builds

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, composer-php, bamboo

I am currently using atlassian bamboo build server (cloud based, using aws) and have an initial task that simply does a composer install.

this single task can take quite a bit of time which can be a pain when developers have committed multiple times giving the build server 4 builds all downloading dependencies (these are not parallel).

I wish to speed this process up but canot figure out a way in which to save the dependancies to a common location for use across multiple builds which still allowing the application to run as intended (laravel)

Comment: Are you committing `composer.lock`?

Comment: no, its in the ignore file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

Remove `composer.lock` from your `.gitignore`

---

#### Explanation

When you run `compose install` for the first time, composer has to check all of your dependencies (and their dependencies etc.) or compatibility. Running through the whole dependency tree is quite expensive, which is why it takes so long.

After figuring out all of your dependencies, composer then writes the exact versions it uses into the `composer.lock` file so that subsequent `composer install` commands will not have to spend that much time running through the whole graph.

If you commit your `composer.lock` file it'll come along to your bamboo server. The `composer install` command will be *waaaayy* faster.

---

Committing `composer.lock` is a best practice regardless. To quote [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file):

> **Commit your application's `composer.lock` (along with `composer.json`) into version control.**
>
> This is important because the `install` command checks if a lock file is present, and if it is, it downloads the versions specified there (regardless of what `composer.json` says).
>
> This means that anyone who sets up the project will download the exact same version of the dependencies. Your CI server, production machines, other developers in your team, everything and everyone runs on the same dependencies, which mitigates the potential for bugs affecting only some parts of the deployments.